# CSS of the header has incorrectly overlapping elements

Tags: html, css, header

I'm currently working on freecodecamp and try to evolve my kind of tribute page.

However, I don't quite get what I'm doing wrong with the styling of the header. Unfortunately the logo and h1 overlap and the text of my li elements of the navbar are spaced strangely. The logo should be far more left. What can I do?

[Picture of my Header so far][1]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

header {
  width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #bcc5d2;
    display: flex;
  align-self: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #252223;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Railway, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Railway, sans-serif;
}

.logo {
width: auto
height: auto;
max-width: 175px;
display: flex;
max-height: 175px;
}

nav > ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

body {
    color: #1b1b32;
    font-family: Railway, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  padding: 30px;
}

#gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

#gallery img {
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding: 0 4px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #gallery img {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

footer {
    background-color: #bcc5d2;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style: none;
  }

footer > ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: Railway, sans-serif;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Jasmin Mühlbach rediscovers Brandenburg</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="RediscoverBrandenburg" content="TributPage">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/JasminCSS.CSS">
  </head>

<body>


  <header class="page-header">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Logo/3.svg">
    </div>
    <h1>Rediscover Brandenburg</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/JasminStart.html">Start</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/AboutRB.html">About Rediscover Brandeburg</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/AboutJasmin.html">About Jasmin</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Reiseblog.html">Reiseblog</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Medien.html">Medien</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/rediscoverbrandenburg/">
        <img alt="Instagram-Link" src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/glyph-logo_May2016.png.webp" class="logo">
    </header>

  <main>
    <div>
    <h1>Selbst Wiederentdecken</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="gallery"
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 09.00.53.png">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 09.01.39.png">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 09.02.08.png">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 09.02.50.png">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 09.03.21.png">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 09.03.48.png">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 09.05.05.png">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 09.05.53.png">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 10.00.24.png">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 10.01.00.png">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 09.07.15.png">
      </div>
    </main>

  <footer>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Kontakt</a></li><br>
      <li><a href="">Impressum</a></li>
      </ul>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could play around with the `justify-content` attribute  in your `header` style selector to get your desired result.

```
    header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #bcc5d2;
        display: flex;
        align-self: flex-start;
        /* This brings all content in it to the center */
        justify-content: center;
        /*
        Try 
         justify-content: space-around; 
        or
         justify-content: space-around; 
         or
         justify-content: space-around; 
         Till you get your result
         */
        align-items: center;
        color: #252223;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: Railway, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your styling has some issues like after .logo width:auto you have to put ";" and also in Html the <div id="gallery" should be closed.

all you have to do is change header css from "justify-content: center;" to "justify-content: space-around;" to get space between your header elements.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I tried this solution. It improved the overall spacing a bit, but still it there is no distance between media and the last logo element which I still don't understand. Maybe you have further ideas!?!

Answer (score 0):

I tried a thousand times and I was able to figure it out. I'm not a native speaker. Therefore, I'm unable to clearly express, what I changed using the right technical terms. So I try it in my own words: it was all about how I addressed the HTML elements using CSS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Jasmin Mühlbach rediscovers Brandenburg</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="RediscoverBrandenburg" content="TributPage">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/JasminCSS.CSS">
  </head>

<body>


  <header class="page-header">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Logo/3.svg">
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/JasminStart.html">Start</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/AboutRB.html">About Rediscover Brandenburg</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/AboutJasmin.html">About Jasmin</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Reiseblog.html">Reiseblog</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Medien.html">Medien</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/rediscoverbrandenburg/">
          <img alt="Instagram-Link" src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/glyph-logo_May2016.png.webp" class="logoI"></a>

    </header>

  <main>
    <div class="headline">
    <h1>Rediscover Brandenburg</h1>

    </div>
    <div id="gallery">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 09.00.53.png">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 09.01.39.png">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 09.02.08.png">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 09.02.50.png">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 09.03.21.png">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 09.03.48.png">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 09.05.05.png">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 09.05.53.png">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 10.00.24.png">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 10.01.00.png">
      <img src="/Users/paulawunsche/Desktop/Webdevelopment/JasminTributePage/Bilder/Bildschirmfoto 2022-06-15 um 09.07.15.png">
      </div>
    </main>

  <footer>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Kontakt</a></li><br>
      <li><a href="">Impressum</a></li>
      </ul>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

header {
  width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #bcc5d2;
    display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  color: #252223;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Railway, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

header > .logo, header > ul, header > h1 {
  padding: 15 px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Railway, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px
  width: 75px;
}

.logo {
width: auto;
height: auto;
max-width: 175px;
max-height: 175px;
display: flex;
padding-left: 45px;
}

.logoI {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 75px;
  max-height: 75px;
  padding-right: 45px;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #252223;
}

nav > ul > li {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}


body {
    color: #1b1b32;
    font-family: Railway, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #EFF2F6;
}

main {
  padding: 30px;
}

#gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

#gallery img {
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding: 0 4px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #gallery img {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

footer {
    background-color: #bcc5d2;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style: none;
  }

footer > ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: Railway, sans-serif;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

Here's my full solution: